# Count of distinct relationships for each node in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The following seems like a trivial query to find distinct relationships for each node:

```
MATCH (n:Department)-[r]-()
WITH id(n) AS node_id, type(r) AS rel_type
RETURN node_id, DISTINCT rel_type
```

And yet neo4j complains:

```
Invalid input 'rel_type'...
"RETURN node_id, DISTINCT rel_type"
                          ^
```

I must be missing something fundamental, as AFAIK `rel_type` is simply a column of strings, over which I should be able to `DISTINCT`.

The goal was to later also count:

```
MATCH (n:Department)-[r]-()
WITH id(n) as node_id, type(r) as rel_type
RETURN node_id, DISTINCT rel_type AS unique_rel_type, count(DISTINCT rel_type) as rel_type_count
```

But that fails with the same error in the same spot.
How do I get the count of distinct relationship types per node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neo4j uses implicit aggregation keys, meaning that all the non-aggregated keys in the `WITH` or `RETURN` statement are used as aggregation keys. You can simply use:

```
MATCH (n:Department)-[r]-()
WITH id(n) as node_id, type(r) as rel_type
RETURN node_id, rel_type AS unique_rel_type, count(rel_type) as rel_type_count
```

The `DISTINCT` can be used to deduplicate the whole row, or it can be used in aggregations.

Whole row example:

```
MATCH (n:Department)-[r]-()
RETURN distinct id(n) as node_id, type(r) as rel_type
```

Or used in aggregations:

```
MATCH (n:Department)-[r]-()
RETURN id(n) as node_id, collect(distinct type(r)) as rel_type
```

You cannot deduplicate only a single variable in a row. Pretty sure you can't do that in SQL either.

Comment: Thank you, I now better understand `DISTINCT`